# Allowing Users to Register Themselves and Post : Does WordPerss Handle these Problems?

Tags: posts, security, moderation

If one allows visitors of a WordPress blog to register themselves and post to the blog without moderation(i.e. without submit for review), malicious visitors may try to

1)Post a large number of posts and fill up the server space

2)Post a few large posts and fill up the server space

3)Create a large number of drafts and fill up the server space

4)Post inappropriate content

Does WordPress have mechanisms to prevent these? Or any plugins to do this?

P.S: If you see any other problems I have missed please point them out as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could call a function whenever a user publishes a post (checkout the publish_post action [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference))

In this function you would first check how many posts your user has already published, and only allow the new post to be published if this number is within a range you specify (ie. < 100)

Then you would check if the post content doesn't contain any "bad words", using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for example.

In any case, I would suggest that any large site where users can publish non-moderated content is a bad idea. Although you can make use of the community to sort out the mess, like the "flag" link here on stackexchange for example, which lets users report a "bad" post.